# Create a database to store Playlists of music

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

I'm building an app which need to story a list of Playlists , and each playlist contains many song:

- Each playlist can contains songs (ex: Playlist A has song :1,2,3...)
- A song can stay in number of playlists ( ex: song: 1 can stay in Playlist A,B,C...)
- Song only has Id property
- Playlist need properties: Name (this property is distinct so I don't need Id property) , Info, ( and I also need to have a number to count songs in playlist , so I don't know if I need a property "Count" or not ?)

Now I'm trying to create a table which contain list of playlist (which has columns: Name, Info, Count), and for each playlist I create a table (which only contain ONE column: ID (of song))

Above solution's quite stupid, but I don't know if is there any better ?

Answer (score 4):

You need a "songs" table, a "playlists" table and a "playlists_songs" table.

The songs table can have "id" and "name" columns as can the playlists table.  The playlists table can also contain your "info" column.  The playlists_songs table can contain "playlist_id" and "song_id" columns referencing both the song and playlist identifiers.  Assuming you are talking about a song count, you don't need to store a count in this table as this can be determined programatically.  If you wish to store a count for the number of times a song has been played this can be done in the "songs" table.  It wouldn't appear to make sense to store count for the number of times a playlist was played (unless this is some type of request) but likewise this can be done in the "playlists" table if required.

Comment: actually "count" is property which I use to count number of songs in 1 playlist. And if I use a "playlists_songs" as you said , is there any problem if this table getting too big ? Will 30 playlists and 1000 songs slow down my query ?. Btw, I'm writing this app in WP8 and use sqlite.

Comment: You should still programatically count items in playlist rather than storing - it is just easier (plus if somebody adds item to playlist you don't need to update the count).  On the numbers - absolutely not.  Those numbers are tiny :)